# Alternatives to SQL? (Alternative declarative query languages for relational databases?)

Tags: sql

I just came across [HTSQL](http://htsql.org/doc/introduction.html), which reminded me of a question I've wondered: what alternative declarative query languages for relational databases are out there? For all the complaints that exist against SQL, I'd expect many, but Googling has been unfruitful.

Various programming languages have list/monad comprehensions, but I'm looking more specifically for something with an actual implementation for relational databases. It would also be great to highlight their major differences vs. SQL (readability, modularity, concision, etc.). The implementation also needs to be open-source, and ideally something I can actually use against an existing RDBMS, e.g. Postgresql.

Comment: As they say on a lot of other sites, **this** .  SQL is a terrible language.  It's difficult to write, difficult to parse, difficult to work with.  It's not even standardized.  Relational algebra is a beautiful thing but it's difficult to see that beauty through the murk of SQL.

Comment: LINQ is not an embedded SQL. The LINQ technology spans databases, XML, in-memory objects, or anything else. It's in no way limited to SQL.

Comment: @John Saunders: yes, I realize that, I was referring to the DB backing of LINQ - *that's* mostly an embedded SQL.

Comment: @Yang: do you mean "LINQ to SQL"? It's not the only "LINQ".

Comment: @John Saunders: Yes, I'm referring to "LINQ to SQL." Again, I realize it's not the only Provider; that it's a general expression sublanguage with multiple backends is irrelevant.

Comment: @Yang: how is it irrelevant? One provider can be considered to be an embedded SQL; all the others cannot.

Comment: @John Saunders: I think we're talking past each other. :) Yes, LINQ to SQL is the only one that's embedded SQL. The others don't have anything to do with relational databases, so how are they relevant to the discussion?

Comment: @Yang: what about LINQ to Entities?

Comment: @John Saunders: Maybe we should try another approach - how does LINQ to Entities (or any provider that for relational databases) make LINQ different, from a *language design perspective*?

Comment: @Yang: I was only remarking on your statement about it being "embedded SQL". LINQ to Entities does not necessarily map one-to-one to database tables, so can hardly be considered "embedded sql".

Comment: Postgresql is not an RDBMS. The "SQL" in the name tells you that it isn't relational. As Malvolio says, SQL pretty much obscures most of the relational goodness. You may want to take a look at some of the TTM "D"-based projects: http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Projects.html

Answer (score 5):

Here's my complete list, with links to illustrative example code (moved examples originally in my question down here):

- [Muldis D](http://muldis.com/Muldis_D.html): Terse Perl-inspired syntax; designed to be a practical full scripting language.
- [HTSQL](http://htsql.org/doc/showcase.html): Very terse; optimized for foreign key joins; somewhat limited expressiveness.
- [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiDimensional_eXpressions):

  > The MultiDimensional eXpressions (MDX) language provides a specialized syntax for querying and manipulating the multidimensional data stored in OLAP cubes.[1] While it is possible to translate some of these into traditional SQL, it would frequently require the synthesis of clumsy SQL expressions even for very simple MDX expressions. MDX has been embraced by a wide majority of OLAP vendors and has become the de facto standard for OLAP systems.

  I think of it as Pivot Tables over RDBMSs.  Pushed by MS (not sure if it's still being pushed - seems old now).  Pentaho Mondrian is an implementation that works with any JDBC provider.
- [PIQL](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~franklin/Papers/socc10armbrust.pdf): the "performance-predictable" language subset of SQL; designed for transaction processing; almost left this out till I noticed a [Rails implementation](https://github.com/radlab/PIQL-on-Rails), though it doesn't look complete so I may remove this
- [Pig](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.134.9888&rep=rep1&type=pdf): marriage of SQL, an imperative style, and a nested data model; due to the nature of the underlying processing framework (Map-Reduce/Hadoop), limited to equijoins; not really for relational databases, so I should remove this :)
- LINQ to SQL (this doesn't really count, as it's mostly an embedded SQL, but what the hell): IMO more natural syntax ordering than SQL; also supports a nested data model

Comment: Hi. So did you pick any in the end? Why? Why not? Do any of these work with Oracle databases? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Example list of Query Languages available curtesy Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_language

Although not all these are for relational databases.

I'll list QUEL, which was stomped out by SQL but is still in use with the Ingres DBMS. Wikipedia says that it is more "normalized" than SQL, but a citation is needed. ;)

Comment: Yes, *most* of them are not relational, most of them I can't take and run on (e.g.) Postgresql, and at the same time it's an incomplete list. It also doesn't consistently highlight the key differences vs. SQL.

Comment: Sure, but I can't think of anything you could take and run on (e.g.) Postgresql. Added QUEL to my answer.

Comment: I listed three that do: HTSQL, LINQ, and PIQL (purportedly runs on MySQL).

Answer (score -1):

Yang, there are two great alternative languages you can use - LINQ and CQuel.

LINQ is Microsoft propreitory while CQuel is open source.

Through CQuel, one can connect to MySQL and MSSQL as well.

CQuel is all new.

You can download CQuel from the link below:
[CQuel Website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cquel/)